# Memory leaks while parsing json string using SBJSon library

Tags: objective-c

When we use the following code to parse a JSON string using the SBJson libray, we're getting a memory leak on the highlighted line. Please check the following code.

```
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init]autorelease];;
    NSDictionary *objDic =[NSDictionary dictionary];
    objDic = [parser objectWithString:jsonStr]; //Memory leak line
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init]autorelease];
NSDictionary *objDic = [parser objectWithString:jsonStr];
```

Does that still give you a memory leak? If so, you need to give a bit more information. What version of SBJson, whether or not you use GC or ARC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Stig: My code is exactly like what you've written. I am using json-framework's current version as of today and my iOS project does not use ARC.